# Qt library, sub classing window to intercept messages?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt

I am, for the firs time, working with the Qt library. I am wondering if there is a way to subclass a Qt widget so you can intercept all the message passed to that widget, it's possibel with windows but I don't know how to do it, or if it is possible with Qt?  Is there an alternative?

The QWidget in question is of type Chat and is of type QList. How is it possible using the QWidget library to intercept anything which is added to a List, which is a widget?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by message.  If you mean:

1 - events, I do believe there's an event handler you can override that is ultimately responsible for passing those events to the specific handler functions.

2 - signals, I have not tried it yet but it *might* be possible to override qt_metacall to behave in an utterly non-standard way.  You will have to find a way to turn void** into something meaningful though and that's pretty damn tough without knowing exactly what you're responding to.  There's an 'id' parameter that tells the MOC generated function what to do and then the rest is switches and reinterpret_casts.

3 - "message" in the object oriented sense where any call to a "method" is a "message".  C++ doesn't work this way, sorry.  If you want that kind of behavior you need something like Java or Objective-C.

Comment: Noah, lets say I had a QWidget called 'chat' and that itself contained a qwidet control which was a list, how would I 'intercept' each time it is added to the list?  Or alternatively, each time an item was appended to the list, could I be notified so that I could then read out the last item?  On point 3 I think it was just my language choice (spoken) - I was really talking about inserting something in the middle so that I get the data as well, when it is added to the qwidget list.

Comment: @flavour404 wouldn't it be possible to simply make the list object a private member of your chat widget, and add a public member function MyAddItemToList(...), which anyone who wants to add an item to the list must call (instead of adding the list item directly)?  Then add whatever additional logic you need to your MyAddItemToList method.  That should be sufficient unless someone is using widget-tree-traversal or other questionable methods to add items to your list behind your back... which they probably shouldn't be doing.

Comment: If you really mean QList then no.  QList is not a widget, it's a container and doesn't generate signals (it can't...Q_OBJECT objects can't be templates).  If you mean QListWidget or QListView then yes, you can connect to its model.  Which signal is going to be specific to your needs.  See: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html

Comment: Noah, if you have a top level widget (a window), using its hwnd is it possible to iterate over its child widgets and find out what class they are?  I am looking for a widget called a CChatView widget which is a QListView and I want to get the items being added to it - is this possible, would you have an example as I am really just starting with the QT library.  Thanks

Comment: No.  The "class" identification (what you use in win32 to do what you're talking about) for all Qt widgets is something like "qt_widget".  You might be able to use the win32 accessibility API but your best bet is probably simply to use the Qt API itself to do what you're trying to do and stay out of win32 as much as possible.

Comment: How would I use the qt api to do that then?  Its a window, I know its a widget, how do I query it, get access to it's 'children' etc?

Comment: What about the 'effectiveWinId' call?  What I am curious about is the function signatures aren't very intuitive?  WId QWidget::effectiveWinId () const; how do I use it?